# Opencv illumination change detection

Tags: opencv, histogram, detection, face-detection, light

Would like to get help from the community for the following problem:
I have two images of faces, one is taken with normal lighting conditions (outdoor or indoor, day or night) and one is taken immediately after the first one but with additional lighting from a bright color screen, e.g. blue Color screen of an ipad or iphone.

I hope to get a grayscale image, where the intensity represents the area in the faces affected by the lighting compensation from the screen. There are two challenges:

1. Face may have moved a bit between the two images. So simple background subtraction doesn't work
2. i want the method to work in various ambience lighting conditions.
3. The lighting from the screen projected to the face could be weak and may hardly detected by eyes under some ambience lighting conditions

Ideally I could obtain a grayscale image which represents the screen lighting. If this goal is too difficult, it is also ok to divide the face into multiple regions and get a summary about how much illumination has changed for each region.

I use the two images of my hand as illustration. In practice, the blue light could be very weak and the hue range may vary. So the method of simply using Hue range does not work well.

[image: Hand image under ambient light]

[image: Hand image under the same ambient light and also the blue screen light]

Comment: is it possible to upload those sample images?

Comment: @JeruLuke, I have uploaded two images of my hands

Comment: Please upload the images in the question my clicking the **edit** option.

Comment: Why do you say hue is not an appropriate choice. There appears to be a distinct difference between the two images visualizing the hue space.

Comment: Depending on the ambient condition, the blue color may not look so blue. For example, if the ambient light is sunlight, the ambient light is yellow or white, the hue range of the screen light may be very different. If I hard code a hue range, it may not work properly. Maybe we could compare the two images, and by comparing we get the range of Hue of the effective screen light. Then I could use the Hue range method. However, I am not sure how to best compare the two images to extract the hue range of the blue light.

Comment: Check out [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671027/how-to-chose-the-optimal-hsv-values-for-inrange-thresholding-in-opencv?rq=1) for **optimal** HSV thresholding..

Comment: were you able to arrive at a conclusion?

Comment: @JeruLuke Jeru, thank you. the answer from that question doesn't work for a few reasons 1) I am not extracting background but the light layer. The light layer is an overlay while the background/object is a region of the image. For example, using proposed answer I may extract the part of the hand with blue light, but there is still hand in it. What I want is the blue layer without the hand. I hope to get a grayscale that represent the blue layer. 2) I believe we cannot get a solution by using one image, the second one. That's why I provided two, one original and one with additional light.

Comment: @jeruluke in photoshop, we can overlay a light layer with the first image to get the second image. The question is can we use the first image and second image to get the light layer?